# Why does this code work only partially?

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

This code is supposed to increment a counter (outputting to LEDs) when one button is pushed and decrement it when the other one is pushed. It works OK with decrementing but on incrementing it changes LEDs to random configuration instead.

```
module LED_COUNTER( CLK_50M, LED, Positive, Negative );
input wire CLK_50M;
input wire Positive;
input wire Negative;
output reg[7:0] LED;

always@( posedge Positive or posedge Negative )
begin
    if(Positive == 1)
        LED <= LED + 1;
    else
        LED <= LED - 1; 
end

endmodule
```

I am using this board: http://www.ebay.com/itm/111621868286. The pin assignment is: 
[image]

The connections:
[image]

After swapping pin assignments for buttons the behavior stays the same.

Comment: This would probably be better asked at the electronics stack exchange site.

Comment: I think it is more related to programming than electronics design. I use a board with a reference design so the problem is not electronical but programming.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is still hardware design, not programming. Verilog is a *hardware* description language, not a programming (software) language. The line is somewhat blurry, however.

Comment: If hardware description is off topic, why are VHDL and Verilog tags listed on SO with such a big user community?

Comment: Verilog and VHDL are really on the edge of SO and SE Electronics. The model of their design and the tools used really falls into SO better than SE:E but when it comes to boards and designing systems with ASIC/FPGA or layout, etc, those are better put in SE:E. Thus, at least the way I view it, it if has to do with the VHDL or Verilog code itself, it fits fine in SO. If its a board-related issue, thats better fit under SE:E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you should be clocking with the `CLK_50M` and you should de-bounce your inputs (some FPGAs do it for you automatically, check your manual).

The reason you see partial functionality is from the way the synthesizer interprets the RTL. If the sensitivity list is edge triggered and that signal is referenced in the body of the always block, then the synthesizer will think it is an asynchronous level sensitive signal. This is intend for asynchronous reset & set (sometimes named clear & preset). ASIC design typically use flops with asynchronous reset in most the design. FPGAs tend to have a limited number of flops with asynchronous set or rest, so check your manual and use sparingly.

With your code, `Negative` is the clock and `Positive` is treated as an active high asynchronous input.

Modify the code to a functional behavioral equivalent (in simulation) seen below, then `Positive` will be the clock and `Negative` will be the active high asynchronous input.

```
always@( posedge Positive or posedge Negative )
begin
    if(Negative == 1)
        LED <= LED - 1;
    else
        LED <= LED + 1; 
end
```

---

There are several resource for learning Verilog available online (use your favorite search engine), and I have some resources posted on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959732/) though more aimed at SystemVerilog.
Here is some pseudo code to point you in the correct direction for your project:

```
always @(posedge CLK_50M)
begin
  past_Positive <= Positive;
  // ...
  case({/* ... , */ past_Positive,Positive})
    4'b0001 : LED <= LED + 1;
    4'b0100 : LED <= LED - 1;
    // ...
  endcase
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no debounce circuitry or logic. A mechanical switch will physically bounce a lot, so your 50MHz clock is going to see many, many transitions on the input signal, leading to erratic behavior.

I forgot to mention that you're not even using that 50MHz clock in a synchronous design. Rather you're asynchronously looking for transitions.

You need a low-pass filter somewhere. Either implemented with analog components on the input signal, or as a counter in hardware.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the negative side works (double registering sometimes, but works) but positive doesn't.

Comment: It may be due to a small mechanical difference in the contacts.  Try to change the pins or contacts and see if it reverses the behavior.

Comment: I did. After changing pins the behavior stays the same.

Comment: OK, then it is probably due to the specific implementation in the FPGA.  The code in `always@( posedge Positive or posedge Negative ) ...` won't map to any native FPGA design elements, like flip-flops.  But it is anyway the wrong way to implement that kind of functionality, so I don't think you should waste more time going down that path; it is more useful for you to start learning implementation of a synchronous design, as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

First, update the design to a synchronous design where state only changes at rising edge of the `CLK_50M`, like

```
always@( posedge CLK_50M)
begin
    ...
end
```

Then add de-bounce logic logic for the two switch inputs; see [contact bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce).  This can be done with a small module you write yourself; that is a good exercise.

Output from the contact de-bounce logic can then be used for change detection, to make a single cycle indication each time a contact is pressed, and this indication can then be used to update the counter.

Comment: Could you recommend a good source for learning verilog from basics?

Comment: Sorry, but I prefer VHDL as HDL; but reviews for Verilog at [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=verilog) is probably a good place to start.